# Passing values between a class component and a webhook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, webhooks

I have a class component and a webhook. Now I have to pass an object from the webhook to the class component. I cannot use { useLocation} in the class component. So, I tried to set the object in the props using react-redux but once I get the value in the class component, I should be able to modify it. I learnt that props value is immutable and cannot be modified or deleted.

Any suggestions on how to achieve my usecase?

Answer (score 0):

Tigger actions with updated data. set updated data to the prop in Reducers. This will update the data in class component as you are using react-redux.

Comment: So I tried this method and it works. I ll do an action and change the props. But is there any other way? This seems more like a hack.